# Why does C give this error ‘size’ undeclared (first use in this function)?

Tags: c

I am a beginner of c programming. I can to write my own malloc function and I put main method code one. It gives following error.

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:

test.c:38:30: error: ‘size’ undeclared (first use in this function)

test.c:38:30: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

code

```
  /*An horrible dummy malloc*/
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <sys/types.h>
  #include <unistd.h>

  void *malloc(size_t size);



  void *malloc(size_t size){
  void *p;
  p = sbrk(0);
  //if sbrk dails , we return null
  if(sbrk(size)==(void*)-1){
        return NULL;
  }
  printf("wada\n");
  return p;
 }

 typedef struct s_block *t_block;

 struct s_block{
    size_t   size;
    t_block  next;
    int      free;
 };


 int main(){
     malloc(50);
     malloc(100);

     t_block  b;
     b = sbrk(0);
     sbrk(sizeof(struct s_block)+size);//Error line (code 1)
     b->size = size; //Error Line
     return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line: `sbrk(sizeof(struct s_block)+size)` you use a variable `size` that you have not defined anywhere. This is clearly stated in the error message.

BTW you should call your function something instead of `malloc`.